# WebDriver ignores Platform Capability

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When I create an instance of Selenium RemoteWebDriver like

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities("firefox", "13", Platform.VISTA);
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(cap);
```

and look into the capabilities inside I see **platform=XP**.

The whole Issue is also described [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Platform%20Vista&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3354)

Is this a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for the user group - try posting here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/selenium-users

Comment: added the link to the bug description

Comment: As said in the bug by the devs (barancev) themselves, it surely looks like a bug.

Comment: appreciate that- if I would have known that this is you I would have asked a different question: "How to accelerate processing of a bug?" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error- description [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Platform%20Vista&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3354).
Looking forward for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem today. If you're experiencing it just like the people are in the [linked bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Platform%20Vista&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3354), it is actually just a problem with the default node configuration. You can set the node configuration manually with a json file, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), under "Configuring the nodes by JSON".

If on each of your nodes, you have a unique json file with entries such as:

```
{
  "platform": "VISTA",
  "browserName": "internet explorer",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
}
```

replacing `VISTA` with your desired platform name, the node will only respond to these requests, and the RemoteWebDrivers will be created appropriately!